# uncommon use of malloc

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

I'm running into this (short) code and I'm not sure what it exactly does;

```
int amount = 5
int totalAllocatedMemory = 0;
totalAllocatedMemory += amount, malloc(amount);
```

It seems that 'malloc' has no effect here!

Thanks

Comment: Sure it has an effect - it creates a memory leak.

Comment: Not a real question, not constructive, too localized... how to decide?!

Comment: The "totalAllocatedMemory" is a different name from "totalAllocatedMemroy" so it may not be doing what you think it's doing. Also, you are missing a semicolon after the first line. In any case, it does leak memory.

Comment: I've seen embedded system malloc "implementations" which allocate linearly and have no (meaningful) free counterpart, so it could be that the `amount` here is moving the malloc linear allocator pointer to an aligned address. I can't think why else it could have been made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have an effect, in that it allocates memory. However, the code does look bizarre and the memory does get leaked.

In case you're wondering about the syntax and exact semantics, see [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

Comment: except the memory never gets used, truly a bizarre piece of code

Answer (score 3):

It:

- Allocates 5 byes
- Adds **5** to `totalAllocatedMemroy` (typo?)
- Leaks the memory

Comment: A nitpick: The comma operator has lower precedence than +=, so it adds 5 to `totalAllocatedMemory` and not the address.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Agreed.  I wouldn't even consider that a nitpick.

Answer (score 2):

Well the code looks buggy but here's what it does:

- Adds amount to totalAllocatedMemory
- Allocates 5 bytes and discards the result (which would be the address of the allocated memory, therefore as others said results to a memory leak)

This is because comma has the lowest precedence of all operators in C.